# Turn off enclosing <p> tags in CKEditor 3.0

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor, paragraph

Is there a possibility to turn off the automatic enclosing of all written content within <p></p> in CKEditor 3.x?

I tried

```
  CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

but this just changes the inline linebreaks to <br /> while leaving the enclosing paragraph.

Currently writing "Test" produces this output

```
<p>
    Test</p>
```

but I want it to be simply

```
Test
```

Is there a configuration property for this or would another inline editor to be better suited for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure ckeditor to not wrap content in <p> block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339710/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-not-wrap-content-in-p-block)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;` - this works perfectly for me.
Have you tried clearing your browser cache - this is an issue sometimes.
You can also check it out with the jQuery adapter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#your_textarea').ckeditor({
        toolbar: 'Full',
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE according to @Tomkay's comment:**

Since version 3.6 of CKEditor you can configure if you want inline content to be automatically wrapped with tags like `<p></p>`. This is the correct setting:

```
CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
```

Source:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Comment: I realize this has been accepted as the right answer, but I don't think it's actually correct. This does prevent the content from being wrapped in paragraph tags, but it also prevents paragraph tags from being generated when they "should" be, inserting line breaks instead. A proper solution would prevent the default <p></p> while still wrapping content in paragraphs when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: For people getting their config from other parts than direct javascript: `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` has a value of `2`. So u can also do `enterMode: 2`

Comment: it does not work perfectly for me: inserting a special character after a BR fails with a NS_ERROR_FAILURE in Firefox

Comment: This looks like a hack and not like a valid plugin configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHellein: It seems that the authors of CKEditor haven't provided such a feature or condifguration option and since it's special behavior then you can go ahead and change the source code to support it. The licensing model is quite flexible.

Comment: @Tomkay: To me it looks like valid configuration since that's the API that CKEditor exposes and not some hidden feature.

Comment: @MaksymilianMajer You can config this. See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Comment: @Tomkay You couldn't at the time when I was writing the answer. I will edit it to reflect new congiguration options.

Comment: I need some config like this but for text special characters for new lines and tabs i.e `\r \n \t`

Comment: Please note on CKEditor 4 autoParagraph : Boolean has been DEPRECATED

Comment: @GibboK can you provide a source for this and a way to do it in CKEditor 4? I'll be glad to update my answer.

Comment: @MaksymilianMajer in their docs here http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoParagraph

Answer (score 34):

Across the internet, people have noticed that setting config.enterMode to CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR removes the wrapping paragraph tags from CKEditor. It's worth noting that the setting changes the behavior of the enter key to insert line breaks rather than paragraphs, which is not desirable.

See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode "It is recommended to use the CKEDITOR.ENTER_P setting because of its semantic value and correctness."

However, the setting that is designed to remove that initial paragraph, config.autoParagraph,  isn't advisable either, as it introduces "unpredictable usability issues" because the editor *really* wants a top-level block element.

See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

The magic happens on wysiwygarea/plugin.js, line 410, where the editor selects the default block element based on config.enterMode. A config option to change the default block element would allow us to start with a div, but we'd continue getting more divs with every enter press, unless we changed the paragraph format via the menu.

See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_wysiwygarea_plugin.js.html

It would be possible to remove the wrapping paragraph tag with post-processing (either on the server or in CKEditor's getData event), but that leads us into the same problem as disabling autoParagraph: there's no top-level block.

I would rather say that there's not a good solution, but rather a handful of half-solutions, than to accept changing config.enterMode as the canonical solution.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm not sure I prefer your final word on this but the summary of relating config options, their implications etc, is good! Thanks1

Comment: Yeah, I'm not wild about my conclusion either. It's really more of a warning than a solution!

Comment: So... CKEditor doesn't see the semantic value in BR tags? They do have a purpose, but it strips them out if the editor is in ENTER_P mode.

Answer (score 9):

Try this in config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

ckeditor.js line #91 ... search for

`B.config.enterMode==3?'div':'p'`

change to

`B.config.enterMode==3?'div':''` (NO P!)

Dump your cache and BAM!

Answer (score 5):

MAKE THIS YOUR config.js file code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

   //   config.enterMode = 2; //disabled <p> completely
        config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; // pressing the ENTER KEY input <br/>
        config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; //pressing the SHIFT + ENTER KEYS input <p>
        config.autoParagraph = false; // stops automatic insertion of <p> on focus
    };
```

Comment: you forgot the `;` behind CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something I'm not proud of as workaround. In my Python servlet that actually saves to the database, I do:

```
if description.startswith('<p>') and description.endswith('</p>'):
    description = description[3:-4]
```

Comment: But if there's multiple paragraphs, won't this result in something like `First paragraph</p><p>Second paragraph`?

Comment: @MaxNanasy, CKEditor always cover values under P tag. So, if your string is "<p>Helo</p><p>Good Morning</p>" then CKEditor converts that value like "<p><p>Helo</p><p>Good Morning</p></p>". derwiki's answer will work always.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (substr_count($this->content,'<p>') == 1)
{
  $this->content = preg_replace('/<\/?p>/i', '', $this->content);
}
```

Comment: <code>
if (substr_count($this->content,'<p>') == 1)
{
  $temp = preg_replace("/<p>/i","",$this->content);
  $temp = preg_replace("/<\/p>/i","",$temp);
  $this->content = $temp;
}
</code>

Answer (score 1):

Edit the source (or turn off rich text) and replace the p tag with a div. Then style the div any which way you want.

ckEditor won't add any wrapper element on the next submit as you've got the div in there.

(This solved my issue, I'm using Drupal and need small snippets of html which the editor always added the extra, but the rest of the time I want the wrapping p tag).

Answer (score 0):

MAKE THIS YOUR config.js file   code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

   //   config.enterMode = 2; //disabled <p> completely
        config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR // pressing the ENTER KEY input <br/>
        config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; //pressing the SHIFT + ENTER KEYS input <p>
        config.autoParagraph = false; // stops automatic insertion of <p> on focus
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Set such config:

```
    CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with me in laravel, with using ckeditor, it work using simple `strip_tags($var)` function for output like below:

Sending value to like this to the other page: `{!! strip_tags($six_answer) !!}`

And/Or when outputting use the same code: `{!! strip_tags($six_answer) !!}`.

the result is below without any `<p>` tags.
[image]

Comment: its works thansk!

Answer (score 0):

{{ blog.description | safe }} just use safe it will remove un-necessary things.

Answer (score -2):

In VS2015, this worked to turn the Enter key into `<br>`

```
myCKEControl.EnterMode = CKEditor.NET.EnterMode.BR
```

Personally, I don't care if my resulting text only has `<br>` and not `<p>`.  It renders perfectly fine and it looks the way I want it to.  In the end, it works.

Comment: This answer does not apply to generic CKEditor and is only valid within VS2015.

Comment: Kosi2801, That is why I said "In VS 2015".  I posted this answer in case someone is specifically looking for a solution for VS2015.  I don't appreciate a negative vote when I specifically stated the platform. Please revise your vote.  Also, please read more carefully before you vote.

Comment: Joe Schmucker, if somebody is looking for a VS2015 solutions there should be a separate question. Your answer does not relate to anything in the original question (how to turn off <p> in the HTML editor CK 3.x or if there are any other editors for websites which could be used instead). I did read your answer very carefully and also researched if it could be applied in any way to the CKEditor 3.x for websites but since it doesn't the answer is not useful. Therefore the downvote and also my comment. Please do not provide an answer for a different problem than the one in question.

Comment: I understand.  I searched for a solution to the problem and I found this post.

Comment: I did not find any other posts related to this for VS 2015 (can you?).Should I ask the question to myself and then answer it myself so that in case someone has this issue they will find my answer?  I am new to this process and I just want to help someone else. That's why I don't like the fact that you gave me a negative vote.  I could use all the positive votes I can get. Couldn't you have just made a suggestion to me instead of down voting it?  I hope you understand my position.

Comment: I understand what you were trying to do. Yes, you can ask a question and answer it yourself, that's actually the best way to go.
Downvoting is not intended to "punish" you or something, it's also part of the mechanism to sort the relevant answers from the not so useful ones. With the downvote the order of answers from top to bottom ensures that answers directly related to the question are listed first and unrelated ones plunge to the bottom.
To get into Stackoverflow, did you already have a look at the Tour? https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I did not see the tour.  I will go through it.  Thanks for taking the time to explain though.  I appreciate it.