# How to configure ckeditor to not wrap content in <p> block?

Tags: ckeditor, word-wrap

I am using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) on my website to make it easier for users to input HTML.

However, the data I get back from ckeditor is wrapped in `<p></p>` blocks. (Which I don't want.)

Is there some configuration setting that forces the editor to not wrap the text in anything?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Add the following to your *config.js* file for CKEditor:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

Example:

```
...

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config)
{
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

    ...
};
```

## Details

The configuration setting that controls this behavior is based on what you want to happen when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Just in case someone who's new to working with HTML reads this, I'm including some basic explanation of the concepts involved and why a tag will need to be inserted when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

We know that if we enter some text into an HTML document and then put additional text on a new line, the browser won't display the text as two lines, it will ignore any carriage returns and will condense multiple spaces between characters to a single space.

The following HTML:

```
qwer
tyui
```

Will be rendered as:

> qwer tyui

So the editor needs to insert an HTML tag to tell the browser that it should display the second group of text on a new line.

The configuration setting that controls this is `config.enterMode` and it offers three options:

#### 1 - Insert paragraph

The default setting creates a paragraph element each time <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; // inserts `<p>...</p>`
```

#### 2 - Insert 'div'

You can choose to create a `div` element instead of a paragraph:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV; // inserts `<div></div>`
```

#### 3 - Insert break (the setting you're looking for)

If you prefer to not wrap the text in anything, you can choose to insert a line break tag:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; // inserts `<br />`
```

[The CKEditor documentation indicates that using the `ENTER_BR` setting is not recommended](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode):

> Note: It is recommended to use the `CKEDITOR.ENTER_P` setting because of its semantic value and correctness. The editor is optimized for this setting.

### Another related setting 'autoParagraph'

There is a second setting that controls a similar situation –`config.autoParagraph`. How it functions depends on the `config.enterMode` setting discussed above.

`autoParagraph` determines whether inline elements such as `span` are wrapped in the block element (`p` or `div`) specified by the `enterMode` setting. The default is to wrap inline elements, so if you enter a span like this (as HTML):

```
<span>asdfg</span>
```

It will be wrapped in a p or div element like this:

```
<p><span>asdfg</span></p>
```

or this:

```
<div><span>asdfg</span></div>
```

The inline element won't be wrapped if you set this to `false` or if you set `enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`.

[The CKEditor documentation includes this note about `config.autoParagraph`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph):

> Note: Changing the default value might introduce unpredictable usability issues.

### Even more settings

There are three more settings that are somewhat related to this subject:

- `config.fillEmptyBlocks`
- `config.forceEnterMode`
- `config.ignoreEmptyParagraph`

### Reference

A complete list of the available configuration options can be found here:

- [CKEDITOR.config - CKEditor 3 JavaScript API Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html)
- [CKEDITOR.config - CKEditor 4 Documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config)

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: You're welcome, it caused me to think about why a tag was being inserted. Joe

Comment: @shybovycha I rolled back your edit. I realize that you didn't know you changed the meaning of the answer with your edits, so here is what was incorrect: I used `<br />` tags to format the answer, they weren't part of the answer and didn't appear to someone reading the answer. Look near the top of the question where it says "The following text:" I was demonstrating that without any HTML tags to tell the browser to display a line break, the text would appear on a single line. Your changes caused `<br />` tags to be displayed, which changed what I had written and caused it to be incorrect.

Comment: @codewaggle oh i am so sorry... Yes, i did notice that and modified my edit. Note: now the answer looks much more better, does not it?

Comment: @codewaggle still, you really need to read the manual on Stack Overflow Markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Using the ENTER_BR setting IS recommended in situations like sending HTML emails, where email readers do not consistently render <p> tags, so it is essential to use <br> tags instead. Otherwise, try to always use <p> tags.

Comment: anyone know how to do this for react integration of CK editor

Comment: Older answer but very informative. Helped me out a bind!

Answer (score 17):

I know I'm a little late to the game, but I think the option the OP is looking for is:

```
    config.autoParagraph = false;
```

Comment: Reason this is probably not suggested: "Changing the default value might introduce unpredictable usability issues." See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Comment: This actually helped me, and it's looking good so far. Any known "unpredictable issue"? =/

Comment: `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;` is not recommended in ckeditor docs: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.autoParagraph

Answer (score 6):

This is answered perfectly well above, however as mentioned you should not really be changing this in the main config.

The correct way to do this is per .replace really.

i.e.

```
    <form name="title" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <textarea id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="300"><?php echo $editor2;?></textarea>
    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="1" cols="50" onfocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;">Type Tab Title Here:</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', { 
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
    on: {'instanceReady': function (evt) { evt.editor.execCommand('maximize');     }},
    });      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

A very simple solution without any configuration change is to use

1. `shift`+`enter` for a line break `<br>`, and
2. just `enter` would cause a new paragraph.

Advantage is that you don't have to do any configuration changes. Plus, you have both.

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to exclude `<p>` tag and want only basic editing tool like Bold Italic superscript Subscript etc in Ckeditor then follow these steps:**

I am 100% sure about this as I researched 36 Hours continuously :)

Step 1: Add this script in your PHP webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { 
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
    on: {'instanceReady': function (evt) { evt.editor.execCommand('');}},
    }); 
</script>
```

Step 2: add `id="editor2"` and `onfocus="this.value='';"` in your textarea like this

```
<textarea id="editor2" name="AsYourWish" onfocus="this.value='';">
```

Step 3: Be sure that remove `Class="ckeditor"` from Textarea.

Step 4: Reload your webpage if not happened Delete Cache/History and Restart PC/laptop.

Step 5: Its Done :)

Answer (score 0):

For `Django-ckeditor` add this config in your `settings.py` file:

```
ENTER_P    = 1 # default
ENTER_BR   = 2
ENTER_DIV  = 3

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'enterMode': ENTER_BR,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here with **ckeditor 5**, don't look for this option. They have **removed it**, I've spent days tyring to figure this out.

> I'm afraid you're not going to like it, but enter mode BR is the root
> of all evil. If we were able we'd removed it from CKEditor 4 long time
> ago and we're definitely not going to implement it in CKEditor 5.

Related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/617)