# Ckeditor adds empty paragraphs when applying a style

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

My CKEditor is adding a lot of unnecessary tags when applying a style to a selected paragraph

I initiate CKeditor with the following html:

```
<p>
    Hi, this a text!</p>
```

When I select the paragraph and apply a style using the toolbar, CKEditor formats my html to the following:

```
<p>
    <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p>
    <span id="cke_bm_173S" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>Hi, this a text!<span id="cke_bm_173E" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p>
    <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Is there any way preventing CKEditor from adding the paragraphs with the non breaking space?

Things I've already tried are adding `config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;` and `config.IgnoreEmptyParagraphValue = true;` to my config file

**Update**
Turns out this problem was caused by the style itself which was a custom defined style. This piece of code was the problem: `{name : 'Heading1', element : 'p class= "subheadingsecondlevel"}`, once I changed it to: `{name : 'Heading1', element : 'p', attributes : {class : 'subheadingsecondlevel'} }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to consider these:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.autoParagraph = false;
```

You can check out my post here for more info:
[How to configure ckeditor to not wrap content in <p> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339710/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-not-wrap-content-in-p-block/7266617#7266617)

The following config setting will stop the editor from inserting a non-breaking space in empty paragraphs:

```
  config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

Was all of the additional code inserted after applying just one style?
What style did you apply, is all the extra code inserted regardless of the style you use?
What happens if you select the text and click the bold button?
Is the code you are showing being copied from the source view of the editor or from the final page that you use to display your content?

Be Well,
Joe

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mind CKEditor wrapping the text in paragraph tags, I just don't want it to add the useless overhead to the code

Comment: Was all of the additional code inserted after applying just one style? What style did you apply, is all the extra code inserted regardless of the style you use? What happens if you select the text and click the bold button? Is the code you are showing being copied from the source view of the editor or from the final page that you use to display your content?

Comment: I added another config setting to the answer, it stops the non-breaking space, but not the paragraph.

Comment: Turns out some custom classes werent properly defined in the js, which caused this problem. This piece of code was the problem: `{name : 'Heading1', element : 'p class= "subheadingsecondlevel"}`, once I changed it to: `{name : 'Heading1', element : 'p', attributes : {class : 'subheadingsecondlevel'} }` everything worked perfectly

Comment: That's great news. In case someone has a similar problem, but with a different cause, I copied the questions from my comment into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Or, if all fails, you can use the CSS selector pseudo-class ':empty' and give it a 'display:none'. In practice, you add this line to your CSS:

```
p:empty {
  display:none
}
```

I understand it's a dirty solution but it works perfectly in most cases and has minimal inpact on design and functionality.

Comment: I'm getting something very similar - empty p block, if the UL is first block in the textarea. Only way to get the rid of it is this CSS hack.

Comment: Entering a `hr`, I get a following empty`p`...with this, I made it go to hell.

Comment: @benzkji - To hell eh? That says to me your design is on fire. But that's pretty much it. Can you please elaborate?