# Javascript WYSIWYG Editor with PHP parsing

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor

I'm working with a prebuilt javascript WYSIWYG editor, and it automatically adds line breaks and paragraph tags where it thinks they're needed. How ever, it's adding stuff where it shouldn't be! One particular place is causing a problem...

I have:

```
<!-- Start: Content Container -->
<div id="container_content">
```

But the editor turns it in to:

```
<!-- Start: Content Container -->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="container_content">
```

So I want to basically erase any data in the middle of those two tags with PHP. I could "rig" it with some explodes and piece it back together...but is there an easier way with preg_replace or regex or something?

------------------- Edit -------------------

I've tried:

`$body = preg_replace_callback("/<!-- Start: Content Container -->(.*?)<div id=\"container_content\">}/is", returnNothing, $body);`

`function returnNothing() {
return "";
}`

but it's not working as expected?

Comment: You may not need `preg_replace`, as stated in your tag. Maybe if you told us which editor you're using and/or post some code, there could be a permanent fix for it.

Comment: removed `preg_replace` from the tag. I'm using http://ckeditor.com/ it's rather a large script, so I figured just parsing the submitted data in PHP would be a lot easier!

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there was a tag for ckeditor! Though again, I'm not really trying to fix it in that part, I'm just trying to parse the data as stated

Comment: I see. Ok, well I also modified your title in an edit. Let's see what comes about.

Comment: So do you need PHP or JavaScript to fix it?

Comment: Looking for PHP! How I would remove the data between the two tags

Comment: Based on what you tried, Try `$body = str_replace("<!-- Start: Content Container --><p>&nbsp;</p><div id="container_content">", "<!-- Start: Content Container --><div id="container_content">", $body);` or what `jerry` posted below.

Comment: But that's the thing, sometimes it adds two or three paragraphs, so I'm just trying to remove any and all the content between the tags as stated.

Comment: Then I think you need `preg_replace` then, and that's a bit more complicated and out of my league, for the moment. If you haven't consulted the PHP manual on it yet, have a look at it here => http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I've also found someone with a similar problem here => (msg:1283680)  http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/4743.htm

Comment: I suggest you post another question with a relevant title, e.g.: **"Replacing multiple instances of <p>&nbsp;</p> within div tags"** or something to that affect, then explain your situation as clear and concise as possible. You'll get the help you need.

Comment: What I think I'll do is just figure it out for myself..instead of sit here and argue over a simple question...because it's being turned in to something it's really not.

Comment: While I Google'd your problem using the following query https://www.google.com/search?q=ckeditor%20adds%20%3Cp%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp - found these links (SO) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268859/ckeditor-adds-empty-paragraphs-when-applying-a-style - and https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8604

Comment: You can also do a workaround for this and add a CSS class `<p class="hidden_p"> &nbsp; </p>` - e.g. `.hidden_p { display:none; }` or `.hidden_p p { display:none; }`

Comment: @c0nfus3d1 **Argue** is a stiff word. And you're **welcome**.