# Why keyup function is not working in CKEDITOR?

Tags: jquery, laravel, ckeditor, keyup

In my application, I have a textarea and I am handling it with ck editor. I am trying to call the keyup function on ck editor and print a text to console on the condition whether it has input or not. But it is not working as I expected and I am unable to find the error as it is not at least printing any errors to the console. Also, I want to get only the text from ck editor (except white spaces) to the variable editorInput. I am pasting my code here, please someone look into this and correct my error and modify it to get only the text. Thanks in advance.

**CK Editor**

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('template_content') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::label('template_content', 'Template Content') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('template_content', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'ckeditor', 
    'name' => 'ckeditor', 'required', 'data-error="Template content is required"')) }}
    {!! $errors->first('template_content', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

**Keyup Function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.on('key', function() {
            var editorInput = CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].getData();
            if(editorInput == '') {
                console.log('no-content');
            } 
            else {
                console.log('has-content');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I found the error. Actually 'keyup' event does not fire in inline editor, but 'key' does. Code edited.

Comment: key function is working now. But still it takes spaces and blank p tags as inputs. I want to avoid these as well. I edited the config.js file with the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268859/ckeditor-adds-empty-paragraphs-when-applying-a-style but I had to avoid my vendor folder when pushing these files to github. So I added the whole vendor folder to gitignore file. Then again it started to accept spaces and blank p tags. So again I removed the vendor folder from gitignore file. But no use, again it keeps accepting those. How to solve this? @AndySong

Comment: Yes, my config.js is in vendor

Comment: No, please check my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example with just js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No! once I installed ck editor to my laravel application, I ran this command to publish the resources: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor. This created a vendor folder inside my public directory and it contains a config.js file. Configurations related to ck editor.

Comment: yes, https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor . Is it possible to use a js functions in the blade file to avoid these in ck editor?

Comment: @anonymus, CkEditor is completely js library, I do not know what's the benefit to use  this php library, and it it not the official one. you can just follow the example code on the official website. I have also provide some sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I need to add a js function to avoid these spaces and empty tags in blade file itself. Is it possible and if yes how to do it? Much appreciated your help on this.