# How to remove unnecessary tags in CKEditor 3.x

Tags: ckeditor

i use the following code...

```
var oEditorText = CKEDITOR.instances["_TEXTAREANAME_"].getData();
return {
   _TEXTAREANAME_ : oEditorText
};
```

Every time when editing one and same record are added a new tags.

How can i correct this,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "unnecessary tags" exactly.

Comment: ckeditor adds horrific additional unnecessary tags. ie empty paragraph tags at the top for no reason at all. Or if you go into 'source' and manually add html, it will 'help' you out and completely destroy it. Its too 'smart'.

Comment: When do you trigger the getData() method? Do you use save function of the CKEditor? Or is the unwanted text added when you insert the data into CKEditor instance? Or are the data in the element that the CKEditor is replacing and unwated tags appear after the instance is created?

Answer (score 8):

You can limit the tags that CKEditor inserts by changing the configuration settings.

I wrote an overview of why tags are inserted in certain cases and explained the use of two configuration settings in an answer to this post:

[How to configure ckeditor to not wrap content in <p> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339710/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-not-wrap-content-in-p-block)

The answer covers more than just preventing a `<p>`. block from being inserted.

The two settings I explained are: `config.enterMode` and `config.autoParagraph`.

`config.enterMode` determines whether content is wrapped and by what tag.

`config.autoParagraph` determines whether inline elements such as "span" are automatically wrapped in a block element.

See that post for more details.

---

I pointed out a few more settings, but didn't describe them. I'll describe them here.

`config.shiftEnterMode` has the same options and usage as `config.enterMode`.

`config.fillEmptyBlocks` determines whether a non-breaking space ( `&nbsp;` ) character entity is inserted into empty block elements. In addition to setting it to true or false, you can set a function to return true or false.

`config.forceEnterMode` will cause the tag assigned in the `config.enterMode` setting to be used when ever there is a newline, regardless of the context. So if `<div>` is the tag assigned in enter mode and you're in a `<p>` tag, a newline will cause a `<div>` to be inserted inside the `<p>`.

`config.ignoreEmptyParagraph` when set to true, which is the default, it says that if there is no content other than an empty paragraph in the content area, the editor should return an empty value rather than an empty `<p></p>` tag.

As Dimon noted there is a `config.fullPage` setting. It is used to indicate whether the contents of the editor represents a full HTML document:

`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

or a block of HTML code as is usually the case.

All of the configuration settings are described here:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Comment: @cosmicbdog, Let me know if there's a specific scenario for which you would like to reduce the tags inserted by CKEditor and I'll see if I can suggest an approach for that scenario. Joe

Comment: Thanks a lot codewaggle. I will see how I go with the advice you have given!

Comment: Your Welcome, I hope you find it to be useful.

Comment: This is a superb explanation!

Comment: @schmunk Thanks, great to hear that you found it useful.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved:

```
fullPage : false
```