# CKEDITOR how to add span to every line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I use ckeditor and I would like to wrap every line with span tag.
For example, when I enter text in the editor I get:

```
this is the first line
<br>
this is the second line of text
<br>
and the third one
```

I want it to be by default:

```
<span style="font-size:12px;">this is the first line</span>
<br>
<span style="font-size:12px;">this is the second line of text</span>
<br>
<span style="font-size:12px;">and the third one</span>
```

I know there is something called "dataProcessor" but I don't understand how to use it.
If it is possible to add this rule also to pasted text it will be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339710/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-not-wrap-content-in-p-block

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help, because I already use: "CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR" and I need along with that to wrap the lines in <span> tag.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Wouldn't it be easier and simpler to style the content with CSS or by using the parent node?

Comment: Because I have some kind of data processor that goes over span tags and resizes them responsively. This was my first thought. Anyway, eventually I did solved it in another way using the parent node and then giving the user the option to change the font size to specific line. Thanks anyway.