# CKEditor forget to paragraph

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-blade

I am using CKEditor in my Laravel front-end project. I would really need to force CKEditor, to forget on paragraph. I mean, I really need to have NO automatically paragraphes there, only if user directly click on paragraph button. Is that possible?

Comment: which version of ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on CKEDITOR version, you could try:

CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;

or

config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; // inserts `<br />`

An interesting answer

[How to configure ckeditor to not wrap content in <p> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339710/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-not-wrap-content-in-p-block)

and link to config doc
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-autoParagraph