# How to reduce the white space between two line in CKeditor

Tags: php, html, css, ckeditor

I want to remove the space between two line in CKeditor. After tpying a line if I hit on enter button then its taking some exyra space between two line. How to remove it. I have highlighted the line space in the image.

[image]

Comment: The space is there because of the default styling of margin-block-start and margin-block-end for p elements.

Answer (score 1):

The space happens, because ckeditor starts a new paragraph when hitting the enter-key instead of starting a new line.

You can change this behavior via the configuration: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/enterkey.html

Comment: Here is a longer and more detailed explanation of the behavior https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266617/17851216

Answer (score 0):

You should use line height in CK editor please check here http://ckeditor.com/addon/lineheight