# How can I put an image outside of the paragraph?

Tags: css, ckeditor

Instead of

```
<p>Hello <img src="helloworld.jpg"> World</p>
```

I would like to have:

```
<p>Hello</p><img src="helloworld.jpg"><p>World</p>
```

`<p>` has a padding of 40px and I would like the images to use all space available.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off paragraphs for all content ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977791/turn-off-enclosing-p-tags-in-ckeditor-3-0)), but as far as I know you can't turn it off for certain elements only.

What you can do is modify the HTML after retrieving it from the database but before outputting it. You haven't specified your server-side language, for C# I've found that [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) is great.