# remove p tag having br tag in php

Tags: php, ckeditor

**I am inserting data in database using ckeditor in php but when I press enter then it generates empty p tag with multiple attributes & br tags having id attributes like that**

> `<p style="text-align:center" id="mf147"><br id="mf148"></p>`

**how can i remove it ? Please give me solution**

Comment: Maybe one of these answers with workarounds or config tips may help: [ckeditor remove empty p and br tags](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20ckeditor%20remove%20empty%20p%20and%20br%20tags)

Comment: you can use strip_tags(string,allow)  at time of insertion

Comment: How come such a paragraph is generated? Can you post your config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try this one for removing the tags you required, please check is it working for you preg_replace('`#<p\sstyle=".*?"\sid=".*?">(<br\sid=".*?" ?>)</?p>+#`','',$string);

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use `strip_tags()` ,The `strip_tags()` function's allowable_tags argument takes the allowed tags in the form <tagname>
```

OR

**CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;**

- this works perfectly for me. Have you tried clearing your browser cache
- this is an issue sometimes.

You can also check it out with the jQuery adapter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#your_textarea').ckeditor({
        toolbar: 'Full',
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
    });
});
</script>
```

Ref

- [Turn off enclosing <p> tags in CKEditor 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977791/turn-off-enclosing-p-tags-in-ckeditor-3-0)
- http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Prevent-first-tags-CKeditor

Comment: He wants to do it server side

Comment: You added it after my comment ;-)

Comment: Yes i have added in my answer but please see my comment at the top i have suggested 2 hour ago but anyway thanks a lot your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom function to suit your need. I made a similar function where i passed youtube embed video code, width and height and the function displayed video in required height, width. Check the following code and make adjustments to make it perfect. I haven't tested it just showing you a way.

```
$str="<p style="text-align:center" id="mf147"><br id="mf148"></p>";
$start=strpos($str,'<br');
$end=strpos($str,'</p>');
$newstr=substr(str,$start,$end-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude tag and want only basic editing tool like Bold Italic superscript Subscript etc in Ckeditor then follow these steps:

I am 100% Damn sure about this as I researched 36 Hours continuously

Step 1: Add this script in your PHP webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { 
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
    on: {'instanceReady': function (evt) { evt.editor.execCommand('');}},
    }); 
</script>
```

Step 2: Add `id="editor2"` and `onfocus="this.value='';"` in your textarea like this

```
<textarea id="editor2" name="AsYourWish" onfocus="this.value='';">
```

Step 3: Be sure that you remove `Class="ckeditor"` from Textarea.

Step 4: Reload your webpage if not happened Delete Cache/History and Restart PC/laptop.

Step 5: Its Done