# CKEditor adds extra <p></p> after a widget is inserted

Tags: widget, ckeditor

When you insert a widget, CKEditor adds automatically `<p></p>` after the widget. This seems like a bug to me. The problem is that it is very difficult after that to remove the `<p></p>`.

[image]

This is just in the root, however the same happens when you insert a widget into editable areas of other widgets. Strange thing is, that when you cut the widget and paste it again it removes the `<p></p>`.

It seems to be a similiar issue as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2448449), however in this scenario there are no strange tags..?

Any way to overcome this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977791/turn-off-enclosing-p-tags-in-ckeditor-3-0

Comment: Nope this is about inserting widgets, I am fine with p tags around text

Comment: The p tags will get generated around any element that you add that doesn't already exist within an element. As far as I know, it's all or nothing for a lot of these WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: @dYale, as you can see in the screenshot the p tags are not added around the widget, but after the widget as empty p's. So this is different, please remove your duplicate flag....

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.6 of CKEditor you can configure if you want inline content to be automatically wrapped with tags like

. This is the correct setting:

```
CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
```