# flux:field.text + CKEditor add new empty <p></p> in backend every save action

Tags: ckeditor, flux, typo3-8.x

When i use my custom FLUX CE with flux.filed.text, every time when i save my text i get new empry line `<p></p>` after aech paragraph.Add empty line between paragraphs like `<p><br></p>`

In default flud_styled_content like TextMedia, Text, TextPic - all fine. Just lags this

```
<flux:field.text name="text" label="Text" 
                 enableRichText="TRUE"/>
```

I tried:

1. swich off autoParagraph
   [Turn off enclosing <p> tags in CKEditor 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977791/turn-off-enclosing-p-tags-in-ckeditor-3-0)
2. Reload configuration and create custom also tried different
   Default, Minimal, Custom, etc.
   https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1388#issuecomment-311618318

I found how clean them in frontend - i just added in output

```
 <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{text}</f:format.html>
```

But I dont like when every element saving i get more and more epty lines

TYPO3 8.7.1 + FLUX 8.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didnt find other solution s as add conditions direct in 'flux'
about line 60 in flux/Classes/Form/Field/Text.php

```
if (true === $this->getEnableRichText() && true === empty($defaultExtras)) {
    $typoScript = $this->getConfigurationService()->getAllTypoScript();
    //$configuration['defaultExtras'] = $typoScript['plugin']['tx_flux']['settings']['flexform']['rteDefaults'];
    $configuration['enableRichtext'] = true;
} else {
    $configuration['defaultExtras'] = $defaultExtras;
}
```

Hope TYPO3 will fix this soon in core or 'flux' will add official pach